# SQL- Column data type difference and performance effect

Tags: sql, performance

I am having a query with join between two tables, check the below e.g.

You would notice that there is a discrepancy between the data types used for the nTransactionId attribute.

```
Table_1
Column Name          Data Type 
______________________________________
nTransactionld       numeric(18, O) 
sValue               varchar(50)


Table_2
Column Name          Data Type 
______________________________________
nTransactionld       bigint
sValue               varchar(50)
```

In the "Table_1" table the numeric(18,0) data type is used and in the "Table_2" table, a numeric(18,0) data type is used.

Since that is the attribute that is likely used in foreign key relationships (see query in below e.g.), would this be causing some performance issues.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table_2
ON dbo.Table_1.nTransactionld =dbo.Table_2.nTransactionld
```

I would appreciate the suggestion's on this

Comment: Not so sure on performance.. but in terms of storage size this may be helpful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d12a3913-b5ad-44e1-b627-c0f9cad3656c/numeric-vs-int-and-bigint?forum=transactsql

Comment: Is this an actual issue (in which case why?) or just an academic question ?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.

In almost all databases, foreign keys need to be the same type as the primary keys that they refer to.  The normal effect is that indexes cannot be used for the `join`s.

That said, some databases might do some conversions under some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The default declaration for `NUMERIC` (a.k.a `DECIMAL`) is 18,0 and takes 9 bytes to store. The maximum precision for `NUMERIC` at 9 bytes is 19,0 so if you don't declare it, you're making a 1 digit mistake.

`Bigint` is good for almost 19 digits... 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and only takes 8 bytes.
The extra byte required by `DECIMAL` is to figure out where the decimal point is. Since you can't use a decimal point in `IDENTITY` columns, I think I'd go for the `BIGINT`.

So as Gordon suggested it makes sense to match the primary and foreign key's data types.